# Filtering data in SPARQL query using python script

Tags: python, filter, sparql, rdflib

I am trying to get uri against firstname literal of the user using following query in RDFlib Python.

```
plugin.register(
    'sparql', rdflib.query.Processor,
    'rdfextras.sparql.processor', 'Processor')
plugin.register(
    'sparql', rdflib.query.Result,
    'rdfextras.sparql.query', 'SPARQLQueryResult')

f1Str="Thomas"

ecsuri= GraphS.query("""
                    PREFIX akt: <http://www.aktors.org/ontology/portal#>

                    SELECT ?akturi WHERE{
                        ?akturi akt:family-name ?fname.
                        FILTER (?fname = """+f1Str+""")

                    }""")
```

It gives following error and it seems to be due to ***f1Str***, how can we filter data in SPARQL using value stored in some variable. Please help.

```
*Exception Type: ParseException
Exception Value: Expected "}" (at char 481), (line:10, col:29)*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to cast your SPARQL variable to string with the `str()` filter

`FILTER (str(?fname) = """+f1Str+""")`

If you need a case insensitive search, you can also do a regex query like this :

`FILTER (regex(str(?fname),"""+f1Str+""","i"))`

Comment: Updated query looks like this but  gives error         **TypeError  bad operand type for unary +: 'str' at statement FILTER**      f1Str="Thomas"
ecsuri= GraphS.query(' " PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> "' +        
+ '" PREFIX akt: <http://www.aktors.org/ontology/portal#> "' +                      
+ '" PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "' +                            
+ '" SELECT ?uri WHERE{ "' + 
+ '" ?akturi akt:family-name ?fname "' +
+ '" FILTER (regex(str(?fname),'"+f1Str+"', "i")). "' + 
                                + '" }"')

Comment: Andy is right, you're missing a quote before and after python triple quotes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `f1Str` is in SPARQL syntax:

```
f1Str="'Thomas'"   # SPARQL quoted string.
```

or

```
f1Str="Thomas"
FILTER (?fname = '"""+f1Str+"""') # Add SPARQL quotes
```

Also, put some newlines in the query string - the error messages will be more useful to you.